# spacing at bottom of footer

Tags: html, css

So I have some wierd spacing at the bottom of the footer and im not sure whats causing it.  the code is as follows:

scss:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
header {
    padding:10px;
    background:#EFDECD; //#5ee;
//    text-align: center;

}

#content {
    padding:10px;
    // padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
footer {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:5em;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#EFDECD; //#EFDECD
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    a{
        padding: .75rem;
       // position:relative;
        top: 1.5em;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: .72rem;
    }
    p{
        font-size: .72rem;
    }
}

video{
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}

.label{
margin-left: .5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
}
table{
font-size: .75em;
}

.panel.callout a:not(.button):hover{
  color: $anchor-font-color-hover;
}
.headtext{
display:inline-block;
    font-size:3em;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:"Courier New";
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 6em;
    margin-right: 7em;
}
.img2{
   // max-height: 20%;
    max-width: 25%;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
   }

.accorborder{
border: black dotted 1px;
}
h6{font-weight: bold;}
```

The site is in development and is at [www.new.omegadesignla.com](http://new.omegadesignla.com) please inspect element to view and can also view source code there.

Comment: @codemonkey : see my answer, but is there any reason for this `<br>` ?

Comment: i wanted a sticky footer via css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the `<br>` which is between `<div id="wrapper">...</div>` and `<footer>...</footer>`.

Comment: Yes, ditch the `<br>`, but I would also avoid the `position:absolute` on the footer.

Comment: i was using a sticky footer format from a web site that works really well and i removed that br and everything looks pretty good now.

Comment: @hopkins-matt Why ? As long as there is a `margin-bottom` on the element before it (`div.wrapper` in this case), there is no problem.

Comment: I was suggesting that avoiding position:absolute could another issue like this. The <br> tag was pushing past the footer. With position:absolute removed, the footer would render below the <br> tag. I can see why you would want position:absolute if you are making the footer sticky.

Answer (score 0):

If you eliminate `position:absolute` from your footer rule, the white space below footer will disappear. Is there a specific reason you are using `position:absolute`?